# Mocking the call to another method of another class inside the method being tested

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, mocking

I am testing a method `A` which makes a call to another method `B` of a different class `C` which returns an `Object` of type `D`. I would like to mock the call to `B()` using `mockito`. How do I do that?

Code:

```
function A()
{
   /*some code here*/
   C c = createC();
   D d= null;
   d = c.B(args);
   /*some code here*/
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, instead of creating an actual instance of `C`, create a `Test Double` version of it, as follows:

```
// Let's import Mockito statically so that the code looks clearer
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

// mock creation
C mockedC = mock(C.class);
```

Then define your **expectations** when something happens on `mockedC`, such as:

```
when(mockedC.B(args)).thenReturn(new D());
```

It says, whenever someone calls `B(args)` on `mockedC` returns an instance of `D`.

Finally you can **verify** actual interactions against expected ones, such as:

```
verify(mockedC)...
```

See [docs](http://mockito.org/) for more details.